# Twilio Voice API - Use "inline" TwiML instead of XML url when creating outgoing call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I'm using the Twilio Voice API to create an outbound call:

```
$call = $twilio->calls->create(
    "+14155551212", // to
    "+15017122661", // from
    array(
        "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
    )
);
```

As you can see, the script used for the call is accessed with the "url" parameter pointing to a XML file.

The XML is hard coded though. Is there a way to write "inline" TwiML inside this create function so I can pass in PHP directly to make the script dynamic? Then I wouldnt be using a hard coded XML file but dynamic PHP instead.

For example, if I have:

```
$customer_name = $customer['name'];
```

I'd like to be able to pass this into the script to be read when a listens to the call.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is currently not a way to create a call and directly give it static TwiML to execute.

If you don't want to host static TwiML you could choose to [host your TwiML in Twilio's TwiML Bins](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins).

If you want the TwiML to be dynamic, but you don't want to host it yourself, you could [use Twilio Functions to respond to your webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: exactly what I needed! TwiML Bins and Mustache. Thank you very much! This also works for outgoing calls too correct? The example provided is for incoming

Comment: Yes, you can use TwiML Bins with incoming calls as well 